# sk_buff_head missing in newer linux kernels

Tags: linux-kernel

In older versions of linux kernel (e.g. 2.6.11) struct sk_buff contains a pointer to struct sk_buff_head (named list). The 'Understanding Linux Network Internals' book says this pointer is maintained as sk_buffs need to quickly look up the head of the skb list. However I could not find such a member in recent versions of kernel (3.2.1). Can anyone explain how the skb list management has changed in newer kernels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changed a long time ago, in 2.6.14 apprently.  The kernel commit in question was:

```
commit 8728b834b226ffcf2c94a58530090e292af2a7bf
Author: David S. Miller <davem@davemloft.net>
Date:   Tue Aug 9 19:25:21 2005

    [NET]: Kill skb->list

    Remove the "list" member of struct sk_buff, as it is entirely
    redundant.  All SKB list removal callers know which list the
    SKB is on, so storing this in sk_buff does nothing other than
    taking up some space.

    Two tricky bits were SCTP, which I took care of, and two ATM
    drivers which Francois Romieu <romieu@fr.zoreil.com> fixed
    up.

    Signed-off-by: David S. Miller <davem@davemloft.net>
    Signed-off-by: Francois Romieu <romieu@fr.zoreil.com>
```